# Distinct zeros of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Suppose $f$ is non-constant polynomial over a field $K$ and $a\ne b\in K$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Then there exists a unique polynomial $g$ such that $f=(X-b)g$, where degree of $g$ is equal to the degree of $f$ plus one. Take $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to be the maximum $k$ such that $(X-b)^k\mid f$. Let $h$ be the polynomial such that $f=(X-b)^nh$.

Is $a$ a zero of $h$? I know that $0=f(a)=(a-b)^nh(a)$: i.e. $0=(a-b)^nh(a)$. Either $(a-b)^n=0$ or $h(a)=0$. I am not able to derive a contradiction from supposing $(a-b)^n=0$. What am I doing wrong? Does this not hold?

Comment: In $K$ the condition $(a-b)^n=0$ always implies that $a-b=0$, since $K$ is a field.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! There's a small error: $\deg g=\deg f\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}} 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$a$ is a zero of $h$. This is because $(a - b) \neq 0$. Therefore, $(a - b)^n \neq 0$ since $F$ is a field and hence an integral domain. Therefore, since $f(a) = (a - b)^n h(a) = 0$, we must have $h(a) = 0$ (again using that $F$ is an integral domain).

Answer (score 1):

If $(a-b)^nh(a)=0$  but $h(a)\ne 0$ then $a-b$ is a zero diviser, so $a=b$, a contradiction.